# chrome-extension:// in Firefox add-on

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm porting a Chrome extension to Firefox. In the Chrome extension, I refer to resources under `"chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id`,

```js
foobar = {
  config: {
    fontURL: "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/fonts" 
  } 
};
```

How to translate this to Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox randomizes the id so even if you write `moz-extension://` it won't help you.

Use `chrome.runtime.getURL` as explained in [`web_accessible_resources` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources):

```
let foobar = {
  config: {
    fontURL: chrome.runtime.getURL("/fonts")
  } 
};
```

`chrome` namespace works both in Firefox and Chrome.

More info on porting Chrome extensions and incompatibilities: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities).